Complex integration and root-finding algorithms
I try to evaluate an integral of the form
\begin{equation}
I(R) = \int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{\left(f(x)+e^{i\phi(x)}\right)\left(f(x)+e^{-i\phi(x)}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
where $f\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ represents some non-negative real-valued function obtained from measurements and $\phi(x) = mx + b(x)$ (with known parameter $m$ and known function $b(x)$). I had the feeling that complex integration could be of help in this particular situation. That is why I reformulate the integral to
\begin{equation}
I(C) = \int_{C}\frac{1}{\left(f(z)+e^{i\phi(z)}\right)\left(f(z)+e^{-i\phi(z)}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}
where $C$ denotes a suitable curve in the complex plane. In this context suitable means that the contour $C$ contains the poles of $\frac{1}{\left(f(z)+e^{i\phi(z)}\right)\left(f(z)+e^{-i\phi(z)}\right)}$. And here my problems/unclarities start. In order to determine, e.g., the first pole I calculate
\begin{align}
&f(z) + e^{i\phi(z)}\overset{!}{=}0\\
&e^{i\phi(z_{\mathrm{pole}})} = -f(z_{\mathrm{pole}})\\
&i\phi(z_{\mathrm{pole}}) = \ln(-f(z_{\mathrm{pole}})) =  \ln\big|f(z_{\mathrm{pole}})\big| + i\pi\\
&\phi(z_{\mathrm{pole}}) = -i\ln\big|f(z_{\mathrm{pole}})\big| + \pi
\end{align}
Since I know the relation between $\phi$ and $z$, I can express $z_{\mathrm{pole}} = \frac{\phi(z_{\mathrm{pole}}) - b(z_{\mathrm{pole}})}{m} = \frac{-i\ln\big|f(z_{\mathrm{pole}})\big| + \pi - b(z_{\mathrm{pole}})}{m}$. However, I don't have an exact expression for the pole since $z_{\mathrm{pole}}$ appears on both sides of the equation. Can you give me some advince how to proceed?
i) Is it still possible to apply Cauchy's integral formula / Residue theorem without an explicit root? If so, how?
ii) If it is not possible and I would really need an exact pole, I could approximate the pole numerically, resulting in the approximation $\tilde{z}_{\mathrm{pole}}$
ii.a) what numerical root-finding algorithms are availabel for solving $z_{\mathrm{pole}} - \frac{-i\ln\big|f(z_{\mathrm{pole}})\big| + \pi - b(z_{\mathrm{pole}})}{m} = 0$?
ii.b) using this approximation I could calculate the residue and evaluate the integral using the residue theorem, resulting in $\tilde{I}(C)$, an approximation of I(C). How do I convert then $\tilde{I}(C)$ to $\tilde{I}(R)$?
Thank you very much for your help, I highly appreciate it.
EDIT: regarding my question ii.a) I just want to point out that I don't have a function given for $f(x)$. I just have measurement values. That is why I believe I cannot use a standard method like the Newton method, but maybe I am wrong here?

I assume your "$f \in \Bbb R_{\ge 0}$" is intended to indicated that $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ is the codomain of $f$, instead of what it actually indicates ($f$ is a non-negative real constant, not a function). You say that $f$ is obtained from measurements. Do those measurements somehow define $f$ as a function on the complex numbers, or just on $\Bbb R$? For Cauchy's integral formula to be applicable, both $b$ and $f$ must be analytic functions, and $C$ must be a closed curve. the interval $[-R, R]$ is not.

So it to be use in finding the integral over $[-R, R], C$ must contain $[-R,R]$ and loop around. The Residue theorem can only give you the integral over all of $C$, so you would need to also know the integral over the rest of $C$. The normal trick for finding integrals on the real line using the Residue theorem is to let $C$ go to $\infty$ off the real line and argue (based on the function) the integral off the real line goes to $0$. But this only gives real integrations of the form $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$, Since $R$ is a fixed finite number, this isn't useful.

Apparently my problem cannot be solved using complex integration. However, thank you for your time and assessment of whether the problem can be solved with this approach.

Since $f$ is obtained from measurements, I would guess it is only known up to some level of accuracy. Thus you wouldn't get an exact answer anyway. You can always numerically integrate the function to get an answer within some acceptable error bound.
